# Understanding the distinguisher for a PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, distinguisher

Given the following definition of a psuedorandom generator, I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the "distinguisher" D is outputting, and when?

[image: defo]

Comment: Please cite the source of the definition you included.

Comment: It was from my lecture notes, but it's functionally equivalent to that of Katz/Lindell's Intro to Modern Crypto..

Comment: I know the practical point of psuedorandomness is the notion that the distinguisher can only negligibly tell the difference between a psuedorandom function and truly random function, but I'm interested in knowing the output parameters of G itself.

Comment: It outputs 1 when it thinks its input was produced by G, and 0 when it thinks it's truly random.

Comment: What do you mean by "the output parameters of G", by the way? The output of $G$ is a string, as is the output of any algorithm, and this string has length $\ell(n)$, where $n$ is the length of the input.

Comment: Woops, I meant the output of D the distinguisher..

Comment: The only thing about $D$ that we care about is the probability that it outputs $1$ in two cases: when its input is $G(x)$ for a uniformly chosen $x$ of length $n$, and when its input is a uniformly chosen $r$ of length $\ell(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D$ outputs a bit $b \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. When $b = 0$, it means that $D$ is guessing that the string it has been given was drawn uniformily at random from $\lbrace 0 , 1 \rbrace^{\ell(n)}$, while when $b = 1$, it means that $D$ believes the string it has been given was produced by the PRG $G$ (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

As said before, the distinguisher D outputs a bit.

I would like to add that the advantage is a measurement for how good the distinguisher is doing. Say you have two distributions which are computationally indistinguishable, then $adv_D$ is negligigle close to 0. On the other hand, if the two distributions are easy to distinguish, then $adv_D$ would be close to 1.

On your formula, the advantage of D is:
$$adv_D = |Pr(D(X)=1) - Pr(D(Y)=1)|$$.

If the distributions are indistinguishable, a distinguisher cannot succeed on doing its job, i.e. distinguishing the two distributions. **Then, the output of D is the same regardless of having distribution X or distribution Y as input.**

If you need further reading I strongly recommend you having a look at the paper "On the Role of Definitions in and Beyond Cryptography", by Rogaway. There he explains clearly the concept of distinguisher.

Comment: +1 from me after reading the "On the Role of Definitions in and Beyond Cryptography" paper. Clearly written and only 20 pages. U can find it: http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/def.pdf